# SSAS Tabular DMV to get source query for a table

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, dmv

Need to get the source query and connection details for measures used in Tabular Model. Have tried below to get measure names:

```
SELECT * from $system.TMSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

We get TableID and measure calculations from above query executed against Analysis Server in SSMS. How do we get the Source query for the table and connection details.

Note:
Below query gives Table Names but not the query and connection details:

```
select * from $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
select * from $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

Note the ID from the table you are interested in. Then:

```
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS where TableID=<ID>
```

will show you query definition(multiple definitions if you have partitions) for SSAS Tabular Model table. Note the DataSourceID, then run:

```
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_DATA_SOURCES
```

This will show you connection details.

Comment: Brand new to SSAS.  I'm trying to execute select * from $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES against a cube and I get no results.  I can query against $System.MDSchema_* sources and get the expected results.  Is there a gap in my understanding?

Comment: @David SSAS can run in Tabular mode or Multi-dimensional mode. TMSCHEMA only works for Tabular. MDSCHEMA and DISCOVER DMVs will work for both.

Comment: Fantastic, that makes complete sense.  Are you aware of how I can query for data sources metadata in a multi dimensional cube? (Probably more appropriate that I ask this in a new post, eh?)